# two compute scalar operators for calculated column in sql server

Tags: sql-server, calculated-columns, sql-execution-plan, calculated-field

I created table CalcColTest and checked the execution plans for queries 1 and 2 below:

```
CREATE TABLE CalcColTest(a INT, c AS a + 1, d AS GETDATE())
```

Q1.

```
SELECT c
FROM CCTest
```

Q2.

```
SELECT d
FROM CCTest
```

Q1 has two Compute Scalar operators in its plan, while Q2 only one such operator. Why is that?

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/152418/why-does-this-execution-plan-have-compute-scalars describes a similar case, and according to the answer there's one Compute Scalar for all the numeric computations and another one for ISNULL. That doesn't apply in my case where I have a simple addition in the definition of the calculated column.

Getting back to Q1, here is the text version of its plan:

```
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([pubs].[dbo].[CalcColTest].[c]=[pubs].[dbo].[CalcColTest].[c]))
|--Compute Scalar(DEFINE:([pubs].[dbo].[CalcColTest].[c]=[pubs].[dbo].[CalcColTest].[a]+(1)))
|--Table Scan(OBJECT:([pubs].[dbo].[CalcColTest]))
```

So .. just an assignment? What for?

Please let me know if you have an idea, I went through a couple of dozen examples on google, found explanations similar to the one above, even found a book saying that you get one Compute Scalar operator per calculated column in the SELECT clause (but one of the calculated columns they requested was not calculated at all, I checked the database), on a different forum about yet another similar example someone said the second Compute Scalar was for "internal purposes". If so, I'd be curious to know why there is such an "internal purpose" for a calculated column that involves another column from the table in its expression, and no such purpose for a calculated column whose expression doesn't include any other columns.

Any help would be greatly appreciated,
Thanks!